# Could not bind to address no listening sockets available

Tags: linux, networking, apache-2.4, linux-networking, rocky-linux

RockyLinux 9. On reboot Apache fails to start with the message

```
Jul 21 10:53:13 cl httpd[877]: (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 1.2.3.4:80
Jul 21 10:53:13 cl httpd[877]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jul 21 10:53:13 cl httpd[877]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jul 21 10:53:13 cl systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 21 10:53:13 cl systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 21 10:53:13 cl systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

The main config file sets it to listen at that address and the 80 port. But there are virtual hosts at that address in both 80 and 443 ports

If I start it manually it starts using that address but the 443 port

```
# systemctl start httpd
Jul 21 10:55:44 cl systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 21 10:55:44 cl httpd[2135]: [Fri Jul 21 10:55:44.803045 2023] [so:warn] [pid 2135:tid 2135] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
Jul 21 10:55:44 cl httpd[2135]: Server configured, listening on: 1.2.3.4 port 443, ...
Jul 21 10:55:44 cl systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Any ideas?

```
# netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      879/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1551/postmaster     
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2574/httpd          
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2574/httpd          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      879/sshd: /usr/sbin 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           810/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                810/chronyd
```

```
# cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/System\ enp0s71fa.nmconnection 
[connection]
id=System enp0s71fa
uuid=b5f5eeee-5bd2-c5a6-acb6-f03d5581aca5
type=ethernet
interface-name=enp0s71fa
timestamp=1689890116

[ethernet]

[ipv4]
address1=1.2.3.4/32,1.2.3.6
address2=1.2.3.5/27
dns=5.6.7.1;
method=manual

[ipv6]
address1=2a01:4f8:bbb:aaaa::2/64,fe80::1
dns=2a01:ccc:dddd::add:2;
method=manual
```

Comment: welcome, Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. Please read carefully step by step [ask]

Comment: @djdomi From the first phrase : *On reboot Apache fails to start*. It is obvious what is the desired end state and the specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to override `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`:

```
# systemctl edit httpd
```

Adding `network-online.target` to `After`:

```
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the new contents of the file

[Unit]
After=network.target network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target httpd-init.service

### Lines below this comment will be discarded
```

Comment: I confirm that under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, that solution works.  I do not understand why by default, it is `network.target` instead of `network-online.target`.  BTW, I replaced `network.target` with `network-online.target`.